# How to call an Oracle stored procedure from AWS Lambda (Node.JS)?

Tags: node.js, oracle, stored-procedures, aws-lambda

How can I call an Oracle stored-procedure from an AWS Lambda function written using Node.JS? We like to pass some parameters to the stored procedure and the procedure will insert or update some tables.

A sample code or link to article related to the subject will be appreciated.

I have read this article "[From SQL to Microservices: Integrating AWS Lambda with Relational Databases](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/from-sql-to-microservices-integrating-aws-lambda-with-relational-databases/)", but it's the other way around - a stored procedure calling a Lambda function.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use node-oracledb, see the doc at https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html

Examples are at https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/tree/master/examples

On Lambda you will need to install Oracle Instant Client, and likely the libaio package.  Check https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/issues/458 for how some other users did this.  There are other resources around too e.g. https://medium.com/@jimdingmac/the-complete-guide-to-use-node-oracledb-on-aws-lambda-using-serverless-framework-and-lambda-layers-52b374d6cfe7